# Connected Metric Space Exercise

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $E$ be a connected metric space, in which the distance is not bounded. Show that in 
$E$ every sphere is nonempty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m assuming that by *sphere* you mean a set of the form

$$S(x,r)=\{y\in E:d(x,y)=r\}\;,$$

the sphere of radius $r$ centred at $x$.

HINT: Let $S(x,r)$ be any sphere. By hypothesis there is a $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)>r$. Show that if $S(x,r)=\varnothing$, then $E$ is not connected. In particular, $x$ and $y$ are in different components.

Comment: Brian, the proof that E is connected when $S(x, r)=\varnothing$ follows that $$E=B(x, r)\cup \{y\in E:d(x, y)>r\}\cup S(x, r)=B(x, r)\cup \{y\in E:d(x, y)>r\}$$ and $B(x, r)\cap \{y\in E:d(x, y)>r\}=\varnothing$.  Right?

Comment: @Roiner: (I think that you meant $E$ *is not connected*.) Yes, though you need to add the comment that $B(x,r)$ and $\{y\in E:d(x,y)>r\}$ are both open.

Comment: Sure Brian, small two details. thank you very much

Comment: @Roiner: You’re very welcome.